# Вывод элементов инфоблока Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Начал постигать битрикс, создал инфоблок.

```
if(CModule::IncludeModule("iblock"))
    {
        $id_block=1;
        $section_id = 0;
        // выберем 10 элементов из папки $ID информационного блока $BID
        $items = GetIBlockElementList($id_block, $section_id, Array("SORT"=>"ASC"), 3);

        $items->NavPrint("пользователи");

        while($arItem = $items->GetNext())
        {
            echo $arItem["ID"]."<br>";
            echo $arItem["NAME"]."<br>";
            print_r($arItem['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['NAME']['DISPLAY_VALUE'] );

        }


    }
```

ID инфоблока = 1, разделов в нем нет. Выводится только название элемента и его ИД. Никак не могу понять как добраться до свойств элементов.

Comment: Исправлено, будьте терпимее к чужим ошибкам.

Comment: В документации же написано что и как делать.

Comment: Я в курсе как добраться отдельно до свойства.  
$arIBlockElement = GetIBlockElement(3,"users_block");  
        print_r($arIBlockElement['PROPERTIES']['NAME']['VALUE']);  
Я не могу понять как красиво воткнуть это, чтобы выводило название элемента и его свойства.

Comment: я бы советовал использовать [`CIBlockElement::GetList`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php)

Comment: вышло, или все же нужна помощь еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгих попыток вышло так:

```
$sResult = "";
    if (CModule::IncludeModule('iblock')) {
        $iBlock = 1;
        $arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_*");
        $arFilter = array("IBLOCK_ID" => $iBlock, "ACTIVE_DATE" => "Y", "ACTIVE" => "Y");
        $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
        while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
            $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
            $sResult = $sResult . "ID element: " . $arFields['ID'] . ". User: " . $arFields['NAME'];
            $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
            $sResult = $sResult . "<br>ID User: " . $arProps['ID']['VALUE'] . ". Name user: " . $arProps['NAME']['VALUE'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: А расскажите - в чём прикол самому руками писать код инфоблока? Штатных средств Битрикса, где всё уже написано до нас, разве не достаточно?

Comment: Здесь я не писал код инфоблока, а брал инфу его элементов.  Все функции здесь стандартные битрикса.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(CModule::IncludeModule("iblock"))
{
    $id_block=1;
    $items = СIBlockElement::GetList(array(), array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$id_block));

    while($arItem = $items->GetNext())
    {
        ?><pre><?print_r($arItem);?></pre><?

    }


}
```

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но таким запросом свойства не вытянутся. Ну и `C` английская должна быть.